# Wpf How to fill a grid with label?

Tags: wpf, grid

I need your help for filling my grid with a label in WPF.

Imagine a grid 3x3.

My code is like that :
MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void CreationDeLaCarte()
{
    Label CaseForet = new Label();
    CaseForet.Background = Brushes.Black;
    Grille.Children.Add(CaseForet);
}

private void CreerLesCases()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            CreationDeLaCarte();
        }
    }
}
```

The result : Just one cell in the grid is blacked. And not the all grid that i wanted. How can i improve this ?

Thank you for your replies ! :)

Comment: if grid is 3x3, why loops have 8 and 10 upper bounds? to put Labels in correct cell you need to set `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties for each Label. if you are interested in MVVM solution, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145391/how-to-create-and-use-matrix-of-color-boxes-c-sharp-wpf

Comment: Thanks for the link ! Yeah, i saw it, it was a example. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties in your loop:

```
 private void CreationDeLaCarte(int i, int j)
{
    Label CaseForet = new Label();
    CaseForet.Background = Brushes.Black;           
    Grille.Children.Add(CaseForet);
    Grid.SetRow(CaseForet, i);
    Grid.SetColumn(CaseForet, j);
}
```

and your loop should look like:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <10; j++)
        {
            CreationDeLaCarte(i,j);
        }
    }
```

Make sure the maximum number of columns and rows are consistent with your Grid.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded.

I have to put some parameters like :

```
private void CreationDeLaCarte(**int i, int j**)
    {Label CaseForet = new Label();
    CaseForet.Background = Brushes.Black;           
    Grille.Children.Add(CaseForet);
    **Grid.SetColumn(CaseForet, i);
    Grid.SetRow(CaseForet, j);**
```