# Binding Data to Button Style with DataTrigger

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm building a menu with WPF but I want to simplify the code creating a new style.
At the moment, the menu is working great:

```
<Button Name="btnMenu1" Grid.Row="0" Content="Button One" Click="BtnMenu1_Click">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding [0].Selected}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding [0].Selected}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
<Button Name="btnMenu2" Grid.Row="1" Content="Button Two" Click="BtnMenu2_Click">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding [1].Selected}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding [1].Selected}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Imagine that I need to add 10 or 15 buttons to the menu, can you imagine the amount of code?
My idea is to simplify the code:

```
<Button Name="btnMenu1" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonMenu}" Content="Button One" Click="BtnMenu1_Click"/>
<Button Name="btnMenu2" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonMenu}" Content="Button Two" Click="BtnMenu2_Click"/>
<Button Name="btnMenu3" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonMenu}" Content="Button Three" Click="BtnMenu3_Click"/>
<Button Name="btnMenu4" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonMenu}" Content="Button Four" Click="BtnMenu4_Click"/>
<Button Name="btnMenu5" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonMenu}" Content="Button Five" Click="BtnMenu5_Click"/>
```

And the code style could be something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleButtonMenu" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

My problem here is: How can I work with `Binding`s in `DataTrigger` to treat the property **`Selected`**?
I have a `List` with properties and when some property change, I need to update UI.
As I said at the top, the code works great, I just want to create a generic style and treat bindings in `DataTrigger`.

Comment: "10 or 15 buttons to the menu, can you imagine the amount of code" - very little: one ItemsControl (e.g [64 buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43100019/1506454))

Comment: I will take a look and try to understand that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your pretty static example, your could bind the `Tag` in your style using a `DataTrigger`.

```
<Style x:Key="StyleButtonMenu" TargetType="Button">
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
   <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag.Selected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then, you could bind the concrete data context to the `Tag` of each button.

```
<Button Name="btnMenu1" Grid.Row="0" Tag="{Binding [0]}" Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonMenu}" Content="Button One" Click="BtnMenu1_Click"/>
<Button Name="btnMenu2" Grid.Row="1" Tag="{Binding [1]}" Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonMenu}" Content="Button Two" Click="BtnMenu2_Click"/>
<Button Name="btnMenu3" Grid.Row="2" Tag="{Binding [2]}" Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonMenu}" Content="Button Three" Click="BtnMenu3_Click"/>
<Button Name="btnMenu4" Grid.Row="3" Tag="{Binding [3]}" Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonMenu}" Content="Button Four" Click="BtnMenu4_Click"/>
<Button Name="btnMenu5" Grid.Row="4" Tag="{Binding [4]}" Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonMenu}" Content="Button Five" Click="BtnMenu5_Click"/>
```

---

However, there is a better way. Whenever you try to display a collection of data items, consider using an `ItemsControl` or any derived type that is appropriate for your use-case. Here, you could use an `ItemsControl` with a data template, since you do not need selection or anything special.

```
<Style x:Key="MenuButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
   <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate">
   <Button Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}"
           Content="{Binding Name}"
           Command="{Binding DoSomething}"
           CommandParameter="{Binding}">
   </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

This data template assumes that your menu item data types contain a `Name`, `DoSomething` and the `Selected` property from your question. Depending on your requirements, the `DoSomething` command might also be definded on the parent data context. This command would handle the button click.

Instead of a `Grid` with hard-coded buttons, you can now bind the items collection (here `MenuItems`) to an `ItemsControl` with the aforementioned data template for your items.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. For now I will use Tag method. In the future I will explore ItemsControl