# How can I control click events in a list of buttons created with a loop? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing an ERP system for a Bar/Restaurant in WPF as a final project for a higher degree in cross-platform application development. On the page where the sales are made I need to handle the events of a variable number of buttons.

How could I get the click event handling on the buttons created in the loop?

This is the C# part:

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
    {


        public string Content { get; set; }

        public string OnClick { get; set; }
        public int distIzquierda { get; set; }

        public int distArriba { get; set; }
        public IList<Button> Botones { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            crearBotones();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void crearBotones()
        {
`Creation of buttons`
            Botones = new List<Button>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Botones.Add(new Button
                {
                    Name = "btn",
                    Content = i,
                    Width = 200,
                    Height = 100,
                    Margin = new Thickness(10),
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML Part:

```
<ScrollViewer
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="2">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Botones}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="6"
                                      Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button 
                            Click="{Binding click}"
                            Width="200"
                            Height="110"
                            Content = "{Binding Text}"
                           >
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMVr5.png)

The part surrounded is tha part of the code

Comment: Why do you create **100** (!!) buttons in the code-behind in the first place? This looks hauntingly similar to x-y.

Comment: it was only a test, a pub can hace 100 diferent types of drinks!

Comment: Then having 100 Buttons _will not work_. This will lead to scrolling, which drives waiters crazy. You need something like a drilldown with favorits. Have direct buttons for ~ Top 10 most sold drinks. For the rest use a drill-down. Like Alcoholic->Beers->Dark->CustomDarkLager, Alc->Wine->Red->France->SomeFrenchRedWine or Non-Alc->Soda->SomeRarelySoldSoda ... You get the gist. Waiters need to get to the right button quickly. You cannot do that with scrolling.

Comment: ItemsControl.ItemTemplate is not applied when ItemsSouce contains UIElements (Buttons). so click event handler declared in xaml is not applied. you can add it in c# code or (better option) change ItemsSource: see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097851/making-a-nxn-tic-tac-toe-gui-wpf-c-sharp)

Comment: @Fildor, 100 buttons in 10 x 10 UniformGrid looks just fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTLgs.png

Comment: @Ash Depends on various factors. Mind that someone needs to actually push them, not only look at them. And then "Pub" is a loud, crouded, shakey environment. I wouldn't be so sure about 10x10 even on a decently big tablet or so.

Comment: But the buttons actually appear, the thing is how i can bind them a click event.

Comment: Well, who is supposed to listen? Can you access the listener from code-behind? If so, you probably can do it from there (i.e. register click events). But last time I checked it was recommended to keep code-behind als vanilla, as you can.

Comment: @Fildor, I remember using self-checkout screen which displayed 10x5 items (basically square with food picture). it might depend on screen dimensions

Comment: @Ash It absolutely does. But also on who is using it and how. I didn't have the alternative idea for no reason ;D