# How to create DataGrid Matrix from List Chars?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, datagrid

I display a `List` with `chars` in a `TextBox`, but the spacing is not uniform.

A B C D E
F G H I J
K L M N O
P Q R S T
U V W X Y

---

How can I bind it to a WPF `DataGrid` so it displays like a uniform 5x5 Matrix?

Or is there another way to make it uniform?

```
A B C D E  
F G H I J  
K L M N O  
P Q R S T  
U V W X Y
```

---

**C#**

```
public char A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y;

public List<char> myList = new List<char>()
{
    A, B, C, D, E,  
    F, G, H, I, J,  
    K, L, M, N, O,  
    P, Q, R, S, T,  
    U, V, W, X, Y
}

public ObservableCollection<char> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<char>(myList);
```

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Height="299" 
          Margin="191,399,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="360"/>
```

Comment: take a look at these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097851/making-a-nxn-tic-tac-toe-gui-wpf-c-sharp, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145391/how-to-create-and-use-matrix-of-color-boxes-c-sharp-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the possibility to use a monospaced font, like

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Lucida Console">
    <Run>ABCDE</Run>
    <LineBreak/>
    <Run>FGHIJ</Run>
    <LineBreak/>
    <Run>KLMNO</Run>
    <LineBreak/>
    <Run>PQRST</Run>
    <LineBreak/>
    <Run>UVWXY</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

you could use an ItemsControl with a UniformGrid:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="5"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Although the XAML designer complains about the `ItemsSource` property, it will work because a string is an IEnumerable and the Text Binding automatically converts `char` to `string`.

You may of course also set the ItemsSource in code behind:

```
itemsControl.ItemsSource = new List<string>()
{
    "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
    "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
    "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
    "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
    "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y"
};
```

or

```
itemsControl.ItemsSource = new List<char>()
{
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',
    'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
    'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O',
    'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
    'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y'
};
```

or of course

```
itemsControl.ItemsSource = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY";
```

Comment: I updated my code. I'm using chars as variable place holders in the List that I can change to different things. I used the itemsControl.ItemsSource = new List<char>(), it is working so far. I have to adjust it and tell you how it goes.

Comment: @MattMcManis You can of course put anything into the ItemsControl. Just make sure the ItemTemplate can display it.