# how automatically generate usercontrols on grid from database? One row from database as one usercontrol on grid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I apologize in advance for my English (I am not a native speaker).

I want to find out how I can automatically generate elements as a usercontrols on a grid from a database. So that one element represents one row from the database. I try to stick to the MVVM pattern.

in the picture below I gave an example of how I would like it to look.

[Exampe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5eSe.png)

I'm really ashamed to show my attempts (I'm a novice programmer), but I couldn't think of anything better to just generate each element almost manually and my code looks like this:

```
public class ListGetter
{
    private readonly List<IListable> _list;
    private Grid _elementGridList;
    private int _rowIndex;
    private int _lastColumn;

    public ListGetter(List<IListable> list)
    {
        _list = list;
    }

    public Grid GetListGrid()
    {
        ResetPosition();

        foreach (var item in _list)
            CreateElement(item);

        return _elementGridList;
    }

    private void ResetPosition()
    {
        _elementGridList = new Grid();
        _rowIndex = -1;
        _lastColumn = 1;

        if (_list.Count > 0)
        {
            ColumnDefinition _columnDefinition1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            ColumnDefinition _columnDefinition2 = new ColumnDefinition();
            _elementGridList.ColumnDefinitions.Add(_columnDefinition1);
            _elementGridList.ColumnDefinitions.Add(_columnDefinition2);
        }
    }

    private void CreateElement(IListable el)
    {
        string labelText = el.GetLabel();
        string descText = el.GetDescription();

        TextBlock label = GenerateLabel(labelText);
        TextBlock desc = GenerateDesc(descText);

        Border elementBorder = new Border
        {
            Style = Application.Current.FindResource("ListElBorder") as Style
        };
        StackPanel btnPanel = GenerateBtns(el, elementBorder);

        StackPanel elementPanel = new StackPanel();
        elementPanel.Children.Add(label);
        elementPanel.Children.Add(desc);
        elementPanel.Children.Add(btnPanel);
        elementBorder.Child = elementPanel;

        MakeHoverElementsVisualSelection(elementBorder);

        AddElementToGrid(elementBorder);
    }

    private void AddElementToGrid(Border border)
    {
        if (_lastColumn == 1)
        {
            _lastColumn = 0;

            var row = new RowDefinition
            {
                Height = GridLength.Auto
            };
            _elementGridList.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
            _rowIndex++;
        }
        else
            _lastColumn = 1;

        Grid.SetColumn(border, _lastColumn);
        Grid.SetRow(border, _rowIndex);

        _elementGridList.Children.Add(border);
    }

    public List<IListable> GetList() => _list.ToArray().ToList();
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Please read [ask].

Comment: I would use ItemsControl with UniformGrid panel. see [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145391/how-to-create-and-use-matrix-of-color-boxes-c-sharp-wpf), [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097851/making-a-nxn-tic-tac-toe-gui-wpf-c-sharp) from my older answers. you need to ccreate your own class for list elements and customize ItemsControl.ItemTemplate